# Is it possible to create popup and exit redirect on aws S3 static website?

Tags: amazon-web-services, redirect, amazon-s3, popup

I just want to know if its possible to create those signup forms that popups when visitor visits the site?
And could visitors be redirected to another site once they click back or "x" button?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can see an html page you can include the javascript code to do that.

The javascript asociated with button click event shoul call `window.location.href = "http://yourothersite.com";`

Comment: Thanks mate. Someone disliked, oh come on am new here

Comment: If the answer helped you please accept it with the green tick.